# Prefetch a cacheline in exclusive mode

Tags: c++, caching, gcc, x86, prefetch

I searched around for this, but was unable to find a conclusive answer.  What parameters do I need to pass to `__builtin_prefetch` to fetch a cacheline in exclusive mode (i.e. after prefetching, the cacheline is going to be written to at some point in the future)?

For reference, this is an outline of the code I have

```
void foo(std::uint8_t* line) {
  assert(!(line % std::hardware_constructive_interference_size));
  prefetch(bytes + std::hardware_constructive_interference_size);
  auto result = bar(line);
  write(bytes + std::hardware_constructive_interference_size);
}
```

Is there even a benefit in adding a prefetch here?  Or will the processor typically always prefetch data in this case?

Comment: `__builtin_prefetch` has optional argument to indicate whether you want to read or write. Please read the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: @gudok I see, so the second argument should be a 1 in my case?  Also the second part of the question - is there a benefit in prefetching an adjacent cacheline?  Or does the processor do that itself usually?

Comment: @xaxxon On a slightly related note - my guess is that the C++ community is probably the best place to go to for questions like this no?

Comment: If they want to answer non-c++ questions, then they can follow other tags.

Comment: I don't think it was correct to remove the C++ tag.  If you're asking how to prefetch a cacheline in exclusive mode in a C++ program, then the tag is appropriate.

Comment: @RossRidge This has confused me in the past as well at times.  Is there some general SO guidance for tag usage somewhere?  I feel like this comes up quite often on questions so would be useful to add if someone has the power to do so

Comment: Yes, guidance is given in the tag description: "Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler."  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: Hmmm, that does seem to direct this as a question suitable for the C++ tag with that wording, I guess if it's alright with @xaxxon we can add that back here?  I would love to have more eyes from the C++ community on this :)

Comment: `prefetchw` is exactly for PF into Exclusive state, in anticipation of a store. https://felixcloutier.com/x86/prefetchw. Supported in Broadwell and later on Intel, and since 3Dnow! with AMD.  (Non-faulting for a long time before that on Intel, but before BDW it didn't set the feature bit and ran it as a NOP so SW like Windows could us it unconditionally.) [X64 instructions that behave differently on different CPUs](//stackoverflow.com/q/40621827).  GCC uses it for `__builtin_prefetch` if it's available according to `-march=`.

Comment: (previous comment copied from the deleted answer to explain why this is a duplicate).